# C# - Un objeto NULL ocupa memoria?

Tags: c#

¿Alguien podría indicarme si un objeto NULL ocupa memoria?

Tengo el siguiente Escenario, tengo una clase `A`, `B` y `C`, y la clase `B` y `C` esta dentro la clase `A`, entonces como estaría la memoria en estos 3 escenarios?

```
1. ClassC C = null;

2. ClassA A = new ClassA()
  A.B = new ClassB();
  A.C = null;

3. ClassA A = null;
```

En esos 3 escenarios, ¿cómo es la asignación de memoria? si es NULL no utiliza memoria? o como se maneja internamente esos escenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**null no es un objeto**... es un valor que te indica que no hay objeto.

Si escribes:

```
ClassC C = null;
Console.WriteLine(C.ToString());
```

Obtendrás un error [`NullReferenceException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Ahora bien, cuando tu dices:

```
ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
```

Hay dos tipos de memoria implicadas en tu código. Está el objeto que fue creado al llamar al constructor `ClassA`, y está la variable `a1`, que guarda una **referencia** a ese nuevo objeto.

Entonces, para responder tu pregunta, **el valor null no hace referencia a ninguna memoria**, pero las variables que tengan ese valor, sí ocuparán siempre algo de memoria. Por ejemplo, en un procesador de 32 bit, la variable `a1` ocuparía 4 bytes (32 bit) de memoria, no importa si está referenciando a null, o a un objeto válido.

Comment: OK entendido, si no fuera molestia quisiera salir de una duda mas, si el objeto a1 tiende a contener un gran volumen de información (por ejemplo un select a una  BD que fue convertido a XML), entonces mientras sea null ocupara 4bytes (en 32 bit), pero cuando ya le asigne el valor tomara el tamaño que necesite? por ejemplo 12bytes o mas? mas claro la variable se inicializa con 4bytes y luego puede crecer según lo necesite?

Comment: No exactamente... la variable a1 es como una dirección postal, y siempre ocupa 4 bytes, pero cuando llegas a la dirección en cuestión, te puedes encontrar una pequeña casa, o un rascacielos.

Comment: Siguiendo tu analogía, entonces en el ejemplo de valor null vs un xml gigante, ambos casos la variable (puntero) tendrá el mismo tamaño, pero el lugar donde apuntan no, entonces sumando el tamaño del puntero + la casa destino, entonces: 

(puntero + null) < (puntero + XML) == true ???

Comment: Si, más o menos... pero recuerda que puedes tener muchas variables apuntando al mismo objeto, como mismo puedes tener muchos trozos de papel con la misma dirección postal anotada. Y ya q estamos en eso, vale añadir que en C# y .net framework en particular, cuando no queda ninguna variable apuntando a un objeto en particular, el objeto se destruye automáticamente (a este concepto se le llama recolección de basura)